# How to make complex conditions in mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

I need to deny access to the whole site for everyone except some IPs.
Also, I need to permit access to one folder of site for everyone:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Allow access only for devs
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !10.10.10.10 [NC] # First dev id
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !11.11.11.11 [NC] # Second dev id

# Allow direct access to files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Redirecting guests
RewriteRule (.*) /coming/soon/index.html [R=307]

# But where to place this condition?
RewriteRule ^/?preview/?$ /preview/index.html [NC]


# Other rules for main site structure
# ...
```

So, I need the whole site loading only for devs. Other users (guests) will see the `/coming/soon/` page
And also guests are allowed to see `/preview/` page of the site.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `/preview/` rewrite is suitable for all users and does not depend on subsequent rewrite rules, the simplest way is to put this `RewriteRule` first with the `[L]` flag, so that subsequent rewrites will not be applied.

Otherwise, exceptions for `RewriteRule` may be specified as `RewriteCond` matching with `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?preview/?$ [NC]
```

Also note that your suggested rule would rewrite both `/preview` and `/preview/` into `/preview/index.html`, and the first of these rewrites may break relative links unless a redirect is performed.